# Telegram bot error Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: Wrong character in the string

Tags: python, python-requests, telegram

I have a .ts file and I want send this file to telegram.

My code:

```
from requests import post

data = open("name.ts", "rb").read()

results = post(
    f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_token}/sendDocument?chat_id={chat_id}&document={data}")
```

and:

```
from requests import post

data = open("name.ts", "rb").read()

results = post(
    f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{telegram_token}/sendVideo?chat_id={chat_id}&video={data}")
```

result:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: wrong remote file identifier specified: Wrong character in the string'}
```

please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the `document` should be done with the `files` param on `requests.post`. Also, you don't need the `read()` on the `open`.

Use the following snippet:

```py
data = open("/private/tmp/test.ts", "rb")

results = post(
    f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendDocument?chat_id={chat_id}", files={ 'document': data })
```